# How can I export a function written in Rust to C code?

Tags: rust, ffi, bindgen

I'm venturing for the first time with Rust's FFI system and bindgen. So far it's going better than I expected but I have now hit a roadblock.

My setup is the following: I have a library written in C that I can compile and that exposes some function declarations for the user to define. So let's assume one header has the following declaration:

```
extern void ErrorHandler(StatusType Error);
```

With bindgen, I now get this function also "declared" (?) in bindings.rs:

```
extern "C" {
    pub fn ErrorHandler(Error: StatusType);
}
```

**How can I now define the function in my Rust code?**

I tried:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn ErrorHandler(Error: StatusType) {
  /* do something */
}
```

However now I get the following error that tells me the function is defined twice:

```text
4585 |     pub fn ErrorHandler(Error: StatusType);
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `ErrorHandler` redefined here
     |
    ::: src\main.rs:7:1
     |
7    | pub extern "C" fn ErrorHandler(Error: StatusType) {
     | ---------------------------------------------- previous definition of the value `ErrorHandler` here
     |
     = note: `ErrorHandler` must be defined only once in the value namespace of this module
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is coming from the forward declaration from bindgen. Rust unlike C and C++ does not have forward declaration. So remove this:

```
extern "C" {
    pub fn ErrorHandler(Error: StatusType);
}
```

and keep this:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn ErrorHandler(Error: StatusType) {
  /* do something */
}
```